# Cannot access phpMyAdmin Web on Docker Dekstop WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I create Docker container for MariaDB database and phpMyAdmin.
When i run the container use Docker Compose i cannot access the phpMyAdmin web on `http://localhost:8080`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mariadb:10.5.8-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./entrypoint:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - db-network

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin:5.0.4-fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: secret
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - db-network

networks:
  db-network:
    name: db-network
```

Comment: Does it work with 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of localhost? Loopback networking in WSL2 sometimes does not work well.

Comment: This page isn’t working :(

Comment: But when i try to create container for nginx i can access the webpage normally on `http://localhost:8080` :/

Comment: Ahhh my bad... i pull image fpm only without web server thats why i cant access it :)